# Omnet++ need statistics on delays

Tags: c++, networking, simulation, omnet++, telecommunication

I have a finished project, it works,
But I need statistics and graphs, but at the end (when the sca file is being generated) Very little information is generated there.
How can I fix this?
[my network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aqBC.jpg)

[statistic in sca-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBryP.jpg)

Comment: What statistics do you require?

Comment: If possible, I need delays in all nodes of this network.
In the Packet Tracer, it is possible to open the console from the terminal and ping any network elements, so I need something similar.